# Proving two domains are not conformally equivalent

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disk. Show that $D - [-1/2, 1/2]$ and $D - \{0\}$ are not conformally equivalent.

Thoughts so far: I'm not sure where to begin, but a hint would most helpful to get me started.

Comment: Conformality is related with mapping in which angles between curves are conserved. But what is meant by "conformally equivalent" ?

Comment: Do you have a stock of examples of things that are not conformally equivalent, so you can try to morph your situation into one of those by biholomorphic transformations?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz 'conformally equivalent' means there is a conformal mapping between the two spaces.

Comment: @Eric Auld I don't have a stock of examples, but I should look for this, thanks!

Comment: An observation to get you started: A holomorphic map $f\colon D-\{0\}\to D - [-1/2, 1/2]$ is bounded near $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any  bounded one-to-one analytic function  $\phi$ on  $ D \backslash \{0\}$
has a removable singularity at $0$.  Thus there is $\widetilde{\phi}$ analytic on $D$ whose restriction to $D \backslash \{0\}$ is $\phi$.
Now $\widetilde{\phi}$ must also be one-to-one, because if $\widetilde{\phi}(0)  = w_0 \in \phi(D)$ there would be at least two members of 
$\phi^{-1}(w)$ for all $w$ in a deleted neighbourhood of $w_0$.   Moreover, $\widetilde{\phi}(D) = \phi(D) \cup \{\widetilde{\phi}(0)\}$ is open.
So any 
bounded domain $\tilde{D}$ conformally equivalent to $D \backslash \{0\}$ has the property that $\tilde{D} \cup \{w\}$ is open for some $w \notin \tilde{D}$.  This is not the case for $D \backslash [-1/2,1/2]$.

Comment: Thank you for the post! A couple questions: why does the one-to-one function have to be bounded? And why would there be at least two member of $\phi^{-1}(w)$ for all $w$ in a deleted neighbourhood of $w_0$?

Comment: 1)  $D \backslash [-1/2, 1/2]$ is bounded.
2) Argument principle.

Comment: I'm not sure why the argument principle gives this as a consequence, could you give me a hint?

Comment: The number of zeros of $f(z) - w$ (counted by multiplicity) inside a simple positively oriented closed contour can be expressed as $(2\pi i)^{-1}$ times the  integral of $f'/(f-w)$ over the contour, and is constant as long as none of the zeros hits the contour.

Comment: Do you mean that the integral is constant as $w$ varies? So the integral will be the same weather the denominator is $f-w$ or $f-w_0$?